# php postgreSQL error

Tags: php, sql, linux, apache, postgresql

I am getting the error

**Warning: pg_connect() [function.pg-connect]: Unable to connect to PostgreSQL server: FATAL: no pg_hba.conf entry for host "::1", user "user_bch", database "test_bchOrder", SSL off in /home/www2.mysite/connect.php on line 8**

on a postgreSQL php connection page. I wonder if it is because the domain is www2 so that my host is not 'localhost'. Perhaps it is something else. [This](https://www.chihost.com/dedicatedservers.php) is the server. Grateful for any help!

Thanks

Comment: Are you using IPV6 on your server? If you dont use it, edit your /etc/hosts and remove ::1 from your list.

Comment: @John Hi, Thank you. How do I tell if I'm using IPV6. And where could I change that? Would there be any other consequences to removing that?

Comment: Since this question is about `pg_hba.conf`, it might be helpful if you provided (a) the connection parameters you used, and (b) the contents of `pg_hba.conf`. Keep in mind that you're posting about access and authentication to a public website, though. The Pg version is also generally good to include.

Comment: @CraigRinger where can I find this `pg_hba.conf` file? I'm a bit out of my depth. postgre version is 8.4.13. And I used these parameters:  `$host = "localhost";
$port = "5432";
$database = "database";
$username = "user";
$password = "password";

$con = pg_connect("host=$host port=$port dbname=$database user=$username password=$password");` Thank you very much!

Comment: @CraigRinger After changing to `$host = "`my IP number`"` I now get the error `Warning: pg_connect() [function.pg-connect]: Unable to connect to PostgreSQL server: FATAL: database "my database" does not exist in url...`  Even though I've just deleted it and recreated it.

Comment: `SHOW hba_file;` will tell you where `pg_hba.conf` is. See [the documentation on `pg_hba.conf`](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/auth-pg-hba-conf.html) and the PostgreSQL tutorial.

Comment: As @CraigRinger said, it would be useful to provide 1) connection string 2) the pg_hba file 3) no, we can't guess where those are in your system / application.

Comment: @John Finally got it sussed with the server admin guy. you were completely right! Thank you! Can you submit that as an answer?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

My comment as an answer:

Are you using IPV6 on your server? If you dont use it, edit your /etc/hosts and remove ::1 from your list. Or else, make sure you configure pg_hba.conf correctly to use IPv6